# BluetoothGattCharacteristic limit causing issues?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my app I have tried everything to connec my BLE device and receive calls to onCharacteristicChanged. I have had success with initial connection where my console reads like this:

```
BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=B4:E6:2D:B3:D0:DB interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 0a990c1f-0000-441c-8f7d-f775b6ff9400 enable: true
BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: f7c21d1c-0000-4b9b-ab7e-e1d8e7a51724 enable: true
```

Although I have no calls to onCharacteristicChanged?

I am not sure this is the proper way to check but I have used [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_US) app to test if there is any activity between the BLE device and the Android phone. Using that app, it recoded no activity after connecting to the device. Just to be sure, I tested other BLE devices and saw the expected activity.

The BLE device has 8 characteristics that I read/get notified from, and another 8 that I write to (16 total). I have read that Android may only support 15, I could be wrong on how this works.

Does any of this seem like an issue? I can post code too.

Comment: nRF can't show the BLE communication made by another app. If you test everything in nRF Connect, does your notifications work if you press the icon to subscribe for notifications?

Comment: No it does not show any communication between the device and app, only when I tap down arrow to force the read. It then only return 0x00. Tapping the multiple arrows down to subscribe does nothing and nothing is recorded.

Comment: Seems like the peripheral isn't behaving correctly then?